# Prove by mathematical induction and determine when there is an equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Let's assume that numbers  $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are of the same sign and that $x_1>-1, x_2>-1,...,x_n>-1$.Prove that $$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)\geq 1+x_1+x_2+...+x_n$$Determine when there is equality.
So I have few questions regarding this problem. I tried two inductions first one$$(1+x_1+x_2+...+x_n)(1+x_{n+1})\geq1+x_1+x_2+...+x_n+x_{n+1}$$
Which evaluates to$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n\geq0$$And we can't conclude anything from that right? How is that that if we just 'change sides' and write this $$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)(1+x_{n+1})\geq(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)+x_{n+1}$$we get$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)\geq1$$and that gives us nothing too? And when the equality holds? Can the answer be formal?

Comment: The reduction is wrong: it should read $x_{n+1}\cdot(x_1+\cdots+x_n)\ge0$ which is a consequence of the same-sign assumption.

Comment: The case $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ is trivial.  The case $-1\leq x_i\leq0$ for all $i$ has been discussed here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873055/can-we-say-that-prod-i-1n-1-x-i-ge-1-sum-i-1n-x-i-forall-n-in-mat.

Comment: In both cases, the equality holds iff at most one of the $x_i$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}(1+x_i)&= \prod_{i=1}^k(1+x_i)(1+x_{k+1})\tag{by definition}\\[1em]
&\geq\left[1+\sum_{i=1}^kx_i\right](1+x_{k+1})\tag{by ind. hyp.}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=1}^k x_i+x_{k+1}+1+\sum_{i=1}^kx_i\cdot x_{k+1}\tag{expand}\\[1em]
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i+1+\sum_{i=1}^kx_i\cdot x_{k+1}\tag{rewrite}\\[1em]
&\geq \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i+1.\tag{all $x_i$ have same sign}
\end{align}
For equality, $x_i>-1$. Can $x_i=0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This is  *Bernoulli's  inequality*. The trick for the inductive step is to multiply both  sides of $\;(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)\geq 1+x_1+x_2+...+x_n$ with $1+x_n$ as you did, expand the right-hand side and use that the $x_k$ all have the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

I think your third inequality is wrong; it seems to me that if you distribute the product in
$$(1+x_1+x_2+...+x_n)(1+x_{n+1})\geq1+x_1+x_2+...+x_n+x_{n+1},$$you should get that it is equivalent to
$$(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)x_{n+1}\geq 0,$$
which holds because all the $x_i$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$(1+x_{ 1 })(1+x_{ 2 })...(1+x_{ n })\left( 1+x_{ n+1 } \right) \geq \left( 1+x_{ 1 }+x_{ 2 }+...+x_{ n } \right) \left( 1+x_{ n+1 } \right) =\\=1+x_{ 1 }+x_{ 2 }+...+x_{ n }+x_{ n+1 }+\left( x_{ 1 }+x_{ 2 }+...+x_{ n } \right) x_{ n+1 }\ge \\ \ge 1+x_{ 1 }+x_{ 2 }+...+x_{ n }+x_{ n+1 }$$